# wordpress4系 画像サーバーを別サーバーにすることは可能でしょうか？

Tags: wordpress

wordpress4系で画像サーバーを別サーバーにするこは可能でしょうか？
もし可能な場合は、設定手順を教えて頂けるとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

プラグインで可能になるようですね
以下のURLを参考にしてください
http://xn--z8j2b8f.jp/web%E3%81%BE%E3%82%81%E3%81%A1%E3%81%97%E3%81%8D/%E3%83%96%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%81%AE%E9%AB%98%E9%80%9F%E5%8C%96%EF%BC%9Fwp%E3%83%97%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B0%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%81%A7%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E3%82%92%E5%A4%96%E6%B3%A8%E5%8C%96/

Comment: 早々にご回答いただきありがとうございました。
参考にさせて頂きます。

ちなみに、Flickr等の既存サービスではなく、
自前の画像サーバーに画像を置くことは、可能かどうかご存知でしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

AWS利用が前提となりますが、絡新婦というプラグインでEC2からS3へファイル転送が可能です。
http://dogmap.jp/2013/03/01/nephila-clavata/

あとはlsyncdでファイルを同期させるとかでしょうか。
http://dogmap.jp/2015/10/27/post-3212/